# Collision detection between entities chasing the player

Tags: c++, 2d, collision-detection

I've been trying to get collision to work with my little top down game.  I have a bunch of entities that are chasing the player.  If I don't have collision, they obviously will all end up bundled in the exact same spot.  I know how to check if there was a collision, but how to react to it is what I can't figure out.  I've got it working somewhat from just messing around with it for a couple hours, but it's not really good.

```
if ( check_collision( enemies[e1]->xPos, enemies[e1]->yPos, SIZE_ENEMY, SIZE_ENEMY, enemies[e2]->xPos, enemies[e2]->yPos, SIZE_ENEMY, SIZE_ENEMY ) == true )
{
      //the distance that is intersecting
    float dx, dy;

    if ( enemies[e1]->xPos > enemies[e2]->xPos )
        dx = enemies[e2]->xPos + SIZE_ENEMY - enemies[e1]->xPos;

    if ( enemies[e2]->xPos > enemies[e1]->xPos )
        dx = enemies[e1]->xPos + SIZE_ENEMY - enemies[e2]->xPos;

    if ( enemies[e1]->yPos > enemies[e2]->yPos )
        dy = enemies[e2]->yPos + SIZE_ENEMY - enemies[e1]->yPos;

    if ( enemies[e2]->yPos > enemies[e1]->yPos )
        dy = enemies[e1]->yPos + SIZE_ENEMY - enemies[e2]->yPos;

    if ( dx < dy )
    {
        enemies[e1]->xPos += (dx / 2);
        enemies[e2]->xPos -= (dx / 2);
    }

    if ( dy < dx )
    {
        enemies[e1]->yPos += (dy / 2);
        enemies[e2]->yPos -= (dy / 2);
    }

}
```

I might have just completely done it a wrong way, or I might be just missing a few things, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might have more luck posting at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

When calculating next position of an entity, check if there would be collision with another entity. If it would be - just don't move this entity at all.

Another approach is to calculate distance and vector from one entity to another. Distance is calculated by Pythagorean theorem: `d = (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2`. If `d` < `2*SIZE_ENEMY`, then they are overlapping and you should move one of them away by vector (x2-x1,y2-y1) for at least dd = `2*SIZE_ENEMY - d`:

newx2 = x2 + (x2-x1)*dd/(2*SIZE_ENEMY)

newy2 = y2 + (y2-y1)*dd/(2*SIZE_ENEMY)

Hope, I have not made mistake in formulas :)

Comment: Also, look at vector math: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector . It is relatively simple, but will greatly help you in 2d games.